# Do new lines in the title element affect SEO?

Tags: seo, html, title

It is a common thing that if you have some login that creates the `title` element content to finish with several new lines in it. For example:

```
<title>
   Title |
   Category |
   My Site Name
</title>
```

Does this has some semantic falls? Is it bad for SEO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New lines do not affect SEO. That won't hurt you at all.

Answer (score 1):

Search engines mostly ignore whitespaces in HTML code so this should definitely not affect SEO.

Answer (score 1):

I would say NO, because if they do affect SEO it means that Google sees differently also:

```
<p>hello babe</p>

<p>
   hello
   babe
</p>
```

which are **exactly the same thing and are rendered exactly in the same way** by any browsers.

Comment: Quick question: If one was working in PHP and added a `\n` to their title in code, would that affect it?

Comment: @Eli Gundry: no a `\n` in PHP code printed out in the page title is rendered as new line so we go back to my answer: it's just a new line ignored by SEO. A `\n` in PHP code that is not even printed out in page is sill ignored by SE because they luckily don't have a chance to look into your PHP script source code.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't affect your SEO, Amit is right: Google ignores whitespace as many designers are not aware of structuring HTML, Google understands the fact well, but - maybe in future it will.

What I would like to ask you is why you are going to do that. I don't think you are going to be benefited in any aspect by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

No, though if it's doing something like this throughout the code it could create a small amount of drag because of the extra whitespace. You may want to investigate minifying your code.

http://code.google.com/p/minify/